# Fabricjs sub-sub-classing

Tags: fabricjs

Subclassing a Fabricjs object is working fine, and is particularly useful for making custom composite objects by subclassing fabric.Group.

But is it possible to subclass the subclass ?   I have not managed so far.

If my first subclass is created by:

```
  var Custom = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, { ...
```

I expected the second level subclass to be created by:

```
  var MoreCustom = fabric.util.createClass(Custom, { ...
```

Any other way to achieve this ?  Or subsubclassing is just to be avoided ?

Comment: You can create as many you want. better use namespace as well. like `fabric.Custom =` and `fabric.MoreCustom =` instead of assigning to a variable, which will be helpful on loading back the object from json.

Comment: Indeed, it works, my mistake was somewhere else, I was calling `this.callSuper('initialize', [], options)` from `MoreCustom`, while `Custom.initialize` had only `options` as an argument.  So this whole question is not very interresting.  Except to know that indeed it is possible.  Thanks.